# Looking for Name of Common Server Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I have been having some trouble identifying whether or not there is a name for the following common pattern:

A *thing* which has at minimum the following lifecycle:

- comes online
- accepts requests for an indefinite period of time
- receives a signal to stop accepting new requests, but finish processing any currently processing requests
- goes offline

I mean this as opposed to something with a terminal lifecycle, something like:

- comes online
- does some work on one request
- goes offline

The most concrete example of this pattern in my mind is a web server which is subject to a load balancer, but am having trouble finding some general literature on the subject.

Comment: The word daemon comes to mind, but that has too many specific associations with system processes, unix, etc -- not so much the lifecycle I'm describing.

Comment: If it's a new pattern, just name it Kevin.

Comment: cheers to the deleted comment: employee vs contractor, nice.

Answer (score 0):

You are just describing the [Client/Server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

The differentiation between 'staying alive' and 'not' really doesn't exist in networked environments, because the server has to 'stay alive' all the time anyways. Otherwise, it wouldn't be able to accept the client's request. (Such as a webserver) The intervention of a load balancer is more a description of the infrastructure's pattern, rather than the server's. Because the server doesn't "require" being shut down. It only "accepts it" when told to.

I've just recently published a paper on a system that quickly starts up processes on demand (our paper worked on a better system & algorithm for load balancing the processes). But the individual processes would still be client/server model despite us starting/stopping them quickly as our system decides(based on time to completion).

---

If you want general literature on the area of Patterns...

There are a few major resources available to you:

Namely the "Gang of Four" Design Patterns book. (Named because of the number of authors: 4) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book) which was one of the first books on the subject.

[Books on Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/POSA/) (full disclaimer, one of the authors of these is my PhD adviser) Each volume of these books covers a different subject area. Vol 2 in particular covers Concurrent/Networked Objects (Servers, etc.) which is directly related to what you are talking about. He also teaches a Coursera [MOOC on POSA, specifically Concurrency](https://www.coursera.org/course/posaconcurrency) that is taught on the Android Platform (but the lessons are applicable to non-handheld devices. Just easier to setup an Android VM, or 'have' a device than it is a 'server')

And if you want *recent* up to date research: [OOPSLA](http://2015.splashcon.org/track/oopsla2015) is held at [SPLASH](http://2015.splashcon.org/):

SPLASH:

> The ACM SIGPLAN conference on Systems, Programming, Languages and
>   Applications: Software for Humanity (SPLASH)

OOPSLA:

> The scope of OOPSLA includes all aspects of programming languages and
>   software engineering, broadly construed.
>
> Papers that address any aspect of software development are welcome,
>   including requirements, modeling, prototyping, design, implementation,
>   generation, analysis, verification, testing, evaluation, maintenance,
>   reuse, replacement, and retirement of software systems.